# Azure DevOps not sending invitation mail when inviting (external) person to their first project

Tags: azure-devops

Our Azure DevOps account is connected to our Azure AD.

If a new developer from a contractor is starting in a project I would

- Go to the correct project
- Click Invite and enter the persons email
- People invited like this never get the invitation email

  - We now have to go into Organization settings and manually resend the invite

Is this some setting in our Azure Ad or is it bug?

[image]

Comment: Are you use Azure DevOps Service or Azure DevOps Server?

Comment: Azure DevOps Service

Comment: If it’s by design that no email is sent, why does the text say that the user needs to click the link in the invitation email?

Comment: Hi, was the invited user a user of your organization leval before inviting it to current project?

Comment: The user was completely new in the devops organization.

Comment: Ok, you're right! There's something strange here about the confusing warnings. I've just reproduced this behavior on my side and confirmed that, but I'm afraid there's no setting can fix the behavior. As a workaround, you can consider inviting users by `organization settings=>users=>add button`, it works well to send the email.

Comment: I'll help to report this issue and come back with the issue link later. Hope it helps~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like for now you need to use Add User button in Organization settings or Resent Invite button to make sure the email can be sent successfully to specific user.

Here's the report about the behavior you met in our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1014793/the-invite-user-button-in-azure-devops-service-tea.html), the team there would help to check that. You can follow that to get notifications if there's any update.

Best Regards

Lance